# NSString with \n or line break

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, newline

Does anyone know how to use line breaks in NSString? I need to do something like this -

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,\n%@", mystring1,mystring2];
```

Comment: Did you actually try this?  Because if you had, you would've gotten your answer.

Comment: no it didn't work. i see the \n appended to the string but when it renders, it is on the same line.

Comment: Please make sure this NSString type message you are displaying not using HTML support.

If using HTML support, it will not treat \n .

Hope i am helpful.
Thanks, 
Aby

Answer (score 180):

I just ran into the same issue when overloading -description for a subclass of NSObject. In this situation I was able to use carriage return (\r) instead of newline (\n) to create a line break.

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r%@", mystring1,mystring2];`

Comment: perfect! Just note that you have an un-needed comma after the first %@

Comment: @OMGPOP, note that for iOS development you also need to check out my answer below.

Answer (score 32):

If your string is going in a UIView (e.g a UILabel), you also need to set the number of lines to 0

```
myView.numberOfLines=0;
```

Answer (score 26):

I found that when I was reading strings in from a `.plist` file, occurrences of `"\n"` were parsed as `"\\n"`. The solution for me was to replace occurrences of `"\\n"` with `"\n"`. For example, given an instance of `NSString` named `myString` read in from my `.plist` file, I had to call...

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

... before assigning it to my `UILabel` instance...

```
myLabel.text = myString;
```

Answer (score 12):

```
NSString *str1 = @"Share Role Play Photo via Facebook, or Twitter for free coins per photo.";
NSString *str2 = @"Like Role Play on facebook for 50 free coins.";
NSString *str3 = @"Check out 'What's Hot' on other ways to receive free coins";


NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@", str1, str2, str3];
```

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",string1,string2];
```

Answer (score 2):

\n\r seems working for me.

I am using Xcode 4.6 with IOS 6.0 as target. Tested on iPhone 4S. Try it by yourself.

Feng Chiu

Comment: this is not an answer..please write these in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Line breaks character for NSString is `\r`

correct way to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r%@",string1,string2];`

`\r`   ---->  carriage return

Comment: "StringWithFormat" is invalid; it should be "stringWithFormat" (must start with lower case 's')

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is the preferred way to break a line.  `\r` will work too.  `\n\r` or `\r\n` are overkill and may cause you issues later.  Cocoa, has specific paragraph and line break characters for specific uses `NSParagraphSeparatorCharacter`, `NSLineSeparatorCharacter`.  [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsParagraphBreaks.html) is my source for all the above.

Answer (score 1):

In case \n or \r is not working and if you are working with uiwebview and trying to load html using < br > tag to insert new line. Don't just use < br > tag in NSString stringWithFormat.

Instead use the same by appending. i.e by using  stringByAppendingString

```
 yourNSString = [yourNSString stringByAppendingString:@"<br>"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3, its much simpler

```
let stringA = "Terms and Conditions"
let stringB = "Please read the instructions"

yourlabel.text =  "\(stringA)\n\(stringB)"
```

or if you are using a textView

```
yourtextView.text =  "\(stringA)\n\(stringB)"
```

Comment: Post is specifically labeled for Objective-C.