# \n does not skip to next line in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, newline

```
NSMutableString *a = @"Hi";

NSMutableString *b =[a stringByAppendingString:@"\n\n Hi Again"];
```

The above doesn't give an error but does not put "Hi Again" on the next line. Why?

Comment: How/where are you attempting to output the mutable string?

Comment: HTML replaces whitespace runs, including `\n` characters, with a single space; that's why there's `&nbsp;`. Whatever you're rendering the string with (WebKit?) could be doing something similar.

Comment: The output is to View on iPhone window

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT2*
 I realised after posting, that the OP had NSString in the title but put NSMutableString in the code. I have submitted an edit to change the NSMutableString to NSString.

I will leave this as it still maybe helpful.

---

Well I am surprised that does not give an error, because you are giving a NSMutableString a NSString.

You need to read the Documentation on [NSMutableStrings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

to give you an idea

```
//non mutable strings
  NSString *shortGreetingString = @"Hi";
NSString *longGreetingString =  @"Hi Again";
 /*mutable string - is created and given a character capacity The number of characters indicated by capacity is simply a hint to increase the efficiency of data storage. The value does not limit the length of the string
*/

NSMutableString *mutableString= [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:15];

/*The mutableString, now uses an appendFormat to construct the string
     each %@ in the Parameters for the appendFormat is a place holder for values of NSStrings
     listed in the order you want after the comma. 
    Any other charactars will be included in the construction, in this case the new lines.
*/
[mutableString appendFormat:@"%@\n\n%@",shortGreetingString,longGreetingString];


NSLog (@"mutableString = %@" ,mutableString);

[pool drain];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459265/nsstring-with-n-or-line-break)*** might help you. You'd rather to use '\r' instead of '\n'

I also had a similar problem and found **\n** works in LLDB but not in GDB

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSString`. You could use:

```
NSString *a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@", @"Hi", @"Hello again"]
```

Comment: Please accept an answer, also did you mean NSString or NSMutableString. You title and code do not match. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If your string is going in a UIView (e.g a UILabel), you also need to set the number of lines to 0

```
myView.numberOfLines=0;
```